# Functions from init.vim to init.lua

Tags: neovim, init.lua

How does

`autocmd FocusLost * call feedkeys("\<esc>")` (back to normal mode, if focus is lost)

translate to lua in init.lua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should do:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FocusLost", { pattern = "*", command = [[call feedkeys("\<esc>")]] })
```

More information with: `:help nvim_create_autocmd()`

Comment: Indeed, thank you :-) !

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If the solution fit your need maybe could you validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)